# Why is my SQL Server CASE statement not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to align these classifications using a CASE statement but the table build is still returning an incorrect value for the 3rd column in row 2 of the results (below). Can you help me figure out why? -- I'm really scratching my head here?

Code and screenshot below:

[image highlighting the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbsYk.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    dom_id = 5, 
    stg1.PVDESC, 
    'bus_segment_test' =
        CASE
            WHEN stg1.PVDESC LIKE '%Process Monitoring%' 
                THEN stg1.PVDESC
            ELSE 'Environmental Monitoring'
        END,
    comm_bus_segment_test =
        CASE
            WHEN 'bus_segment_test' LIKE '%Process Monitoring%' 
                THEN 'Process Monitoring'
            ELSE 'Environmental Monitoring'
        END
    FROM 
        CDW_Staging.dbo.STG_1_ERP0005_BILL AS stg1
```

Row 2 in the following output table shows the undesired results (because incorrectly showing 'Environmental Monitoring' in Col3 when it should say 'Process Monitoring'):

| dom_id | PVDESC | bus_segment_test | comm_bus_segment_test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | BioAerosol | Environmental Monitoring | Environmental Monitoring |
| 5 | Process Monitoring | Process Monitoring | Environmental Monitoring |
| 5 | Franklin Systems | Environmental Monitoring | Environmental Monitoring |
| 5 | Franklin | Environmental Monitoring | Environmental Monitoring |
| 5 | West Columbia | Environmental Monitoring | Environmental Monitoring |
| 5 | Coal | Environmental Monitoring | Environmental Monitoring |

Comment: You cannot refer to an aliased column in the same `SELECT` clause that introduces it, so your second test is testing the literal string `'bus_segment_test'`, which of course does not match. Make it a habit to *not* use the string literal syntax for identifiers; this is a T-SQL wart that just confuses. Use `[identifier]` or `"identifier"`, but never `'identifier'`.

Comment: There are numerous syntax errors in your code - the output shown cannot have been produced by your code; please correct it. For starters, where you have `xxx = case ... end` should be `case ... end as xxx`. Also, it would be helpful to show sample data and expected output.

Comment: The syntax `'Literal String Alias' = Expression` is also deprecated. Though it's recommended to not use literal string aliases, it's **strongly** recommended to not use that style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second CASE statement is comparing the string 'bus_segment_test' to '%Process Monitoring%'. I'd change `WHEN 'bus_segment_test' LIKE '%Process Monitoring%' THEN 'Process Monitoring'` to `WHEN stg1.PVDESC LIKE '%Process Monitoring%' THEN 'Process Monitoring'`

Comment: this would count as typo and would imply a close reason